# Windows - is there a command-line interface for GMail?

Tags: windows, command-line, email, gmail, email-filter

There was a command line interface to the Google API (I'm unsure if it supported Gmail), but it is now [defunct](https://code.google.com/archive/p/googlecl/):

`8 June 2015: GoogleCL is currently broken due to the OAuth1 turndown, and likely to remain so. Thanks for your support over the years, and apologies for the lack of prior notice.`

Is there any way of manipulating Gmail via a Windows command prompt?  I'm particularly interested in creating and updating email filters.

Answer (score 1):

Not specifically for GMail, so there's probably no way to create e-mail filters for your web account from a CLI if that's what you are referring to, but I recently found out about `Alpine`, and its fork `re-alpine` which are cross-platform terminal-based e-mail clients capable of understanding a lot of different e-mail protocols.

`Alpine` or `re-alpine` can be used to compose and receive mails for and from a GMail account.

I have never tried it, so I do not know what the extent of its capabilities are beyond that, but there are several guides for it and it seems to be quite powerful.
It does provide a view of the folders within your account, so it might even be capable of setting up filters.

The thing I'm almost sure it is not that good for is automation, as it uses a TUI (Textual User Interface) library, so you'd need a special program for automating it.

EDIT: There is also `msmtp`, recommended to me by a colleague, which is entirely command-line based in the traditional sense.